# TypeError: dispatch is not a function React and Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

I get an error when I delete some lead(item). It deletes from the database but not from UI and gives this error `dispatch is not a function.`

```js
//lead.js from /action
export const deleteLead = (id) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios
      .delete(`/api/leads/${id}/`)
      .then((res) => {
        dispatch({
          type: DELETE_LEAD,
          payload: id,
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
};
```

```js
//Frontend file 
import { getLeads, deleteLead } from "../../actions/leads";

<button
  onClick={deleteLead(lead.id)}
  className="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
   Delete
</button>
```

Comment: A typo?  You probably meant to pass a function to `onClick` instead: `onClick={() => deleteLead(lead.id)}`  But even then it's not really clear where you actually dispatch to Redux.  Where do you include/use anything from Redux here?  Currently you just have a function that returns a function.

Comment: @David it's not working

Comment: It's a step in the right direction.  But where is Redux actually used here?  Calling `deleteLead()` returns a function.  What do you do with that function?  (In the code shown that function is used as a click handler, and the environment passes an event object to a click handler, not a function.)

Comment: Removed `django` tag

Answer (score 4):

`deleteLead` is an action creator. Calling it with `deleteLead(lead.id)` creates an action, which you then need to dispatch.

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

const YourComponent = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch() // or however else you want to get redux's dispatch function

  return (
    <button onClick={() => dispatch(deleteLead(lead.id))}>
      Delete
    </button>
  )
}
```

To be able to use an action creator that returns a function instead of a plain action object, you will need to use the `redux-thunk` middleware.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the problem, but certainly you should have this:

```
<button
  onClick={() => deleteLead(lead.id)}
  className="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
   Delete
</button>
```

Your code as provided will call the deleteLead function as soon as the component is rendered!